# How to migrate(convert) database(or just tables) from PostgreSQL to Oracle using only Oracle tools?

Tags: oracle, postgresql

Data was sent to our company with PostgreSQL, but we are prohibited to use the tools of PostgreSQL , permitted the use of only Oracle.

How to migrate data from PostgreSQL to Oracle without using a third party application(they are also prohibited)? You can only use the tools of Oracle.

I found this article https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2220826_1.html but we don't have *Support Identifier*

We have one `.sql` file. It weighs 8 Gigabytes.

Comment: In what form were the data sent?

Comment: Specific files, not .txt or .csv

Comment: What "specific files" are you talking about? A SQL dump generated using `pg_dump -Fp`? Or a custom dump generated using `pg_dump -Fc`? Something else entirely?

Comment: To be honest, I am trainee. I have a task to know "Can we migrate dump postgresql to oracle?". I don't know what dump: `pg_dump -Fc` or `pg_dump -Fp`

Comment: Oracle as a (free) GUI tool named SQL Developer that allows to migrate from non-Oracle databases to Oracle. It can connect to non Oracle databases using JDBC but migration process needs to have connection to source database: it could be easier to restore PG data into a local PG instance and to migrate using SQL Developer than to work with files.

Comment: This is not a suitable task for a trainee, unless it's some kind of initiative test.

Comment: What names and extensions do the files have?

Comment: I don't know. *.ddf* seem

Comment: what about dblink from oracle to postgre?

Comment: `.ddf` is not a standard extension any Postgres tool uses. You will need to clarify with the source of the files and ask them what exactly they are.

Comment: Could you please post the results of the running the `file FILENAME` and `od -c FILENAME | head` commands so that we may be able to look at what the file format actually is?

Comment: We have `.sql` file. It weighs 8 Gigabytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have so many impediments in your company. Regarding Oracle's SQL Developer Migration Workbench, unfortunately it does not support the migration of PostgreSQL databases. However, the following 3rd-party software tools are available and may assist in migration, but I am afraid you cannot use them as you said that those products are forbidden:

http://www.easyfrom.net/download/?gclid=CNPntY36vsQCFUoqjgodHnsA0w#.VRBHKGPVuRQ
http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql-to-oracle

Other options will only move the data from your Postgresql database to Oracle database, it means that you must have the DDLs of the tables before to run the import:

- To move data only, you can generate a flat file of the  the
  PostgreSQL data and use Oracle SQL*Loader.
- Another option to migrate data only  is to use Oracle Database
  Gateway for ODBC which requires an ODBC driver to connect to the
  PostreSQL database, and copy each table over the network using
  sqlplus "COPY" or "CREATE TABLE AS SELECT" commands via oracle
  database link.

Also, Oracle has discussion forum for migrating non-oracle databases to Oracle.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/third-party-093040.html

But, if you have only a sql file, you should look at it to see whether you have both DDLs ( create tables and indexes, etc ) and the data itself as insert statements. If so, you need to split it and treat the DDLs to convert the original data types to Oracle datatypes.